# Copy files in Linux, avoid the copy if files do exist in destination

Tags: cp

I need to copy a /home/user folder from one hard disk to another one. It has 100,000 files and around 10G size.

I use

> `cp -r /origin /destination`

sometimes I get some errors due to broken links, permissions and so on. So I fix the error, and need to start again the copy.

I wonder how could I tell the command "cp", once it tries to copy again, not to copy files again if they exist in the destination folder.

Comment: Don't us cp. Use rsync instead.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`cp -R -u -p /source /destination`

The `-u` (*or `--update`*) flag does just this:

From the man page for cp:

> -u, --update
>
> copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing

Comment: To literally only copy files that don't exist and not update existing ones, 
`yes n | cp -i /source/* /destination 2>/dev/null`

Comment: -u, --update
              copy only when the SOURCE file is  newer  than  the  destination
              file or when the destination file is missing

       -u, --update
              copy only when the SOURCE file is  newer  than  the  destination
              file or when the destination file is missing

       -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

       --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,time‐
              stamps), if  possible  additional  attributes:  context,  links,
              xattr, all

Comment: There is no `-u` option on my Mac. I think `-n` option can be used which means "Do not overwrite an existing file" according to the man page. I see that is in another answer. Troubling that different systems don't agree on something as fundamental as `cp`.

Answer (score 211):

Just use `cp -n <source> <dest>`.

*From [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):*

> -n, --no-clobber
>
> do NOT overwrite an existing file (overrides a previous -i option)

Comment: This is the only true answer to the question.

Comment: @sebix OP says "sometimes I get some errors [...] and need to start again the copy" Unless I'm mistaken, this solution wouldn't overwrite corrupt files at the destination by re-copying, so you could end up with a bunch of corrupt files at the destination, while thinking that the copy process has been successful.

Comment: @joe interesting remark, but the op explicitely asks for a way to skip copying files which already exist in the destination.  I guess **rsync** would be a better choice, if one wants to validate the files integrity.
(*note that re-copying everything wouldn't help much, and could as well replace some valid files with corrupted ones.*)

Comment: @Balmipour Yep, `rsync` is a better approach here. "but the op explicitly asks [...]" It's quite clear from OP's post that they wouldn't want corrupt/half-copied files at the destination.

Answer (score 30):

`rsync -aq /src /dest`

Apart from only copying newer files, it will even only copy the newer parts of files if the file has changed. It's intended for copying over network links where you want to minimise the amount of data - but it also works great locally.

Comment: If you are familiar with the interface of rsync then by all means use it, but the delta copy feature only happens when using it over a remote transport.  When used on local paths it disables that feature because it would likely slow it down instead of speeding it up.
It's also worth pointing out the default behavior of rsync is to replace an existing file if the modification time or size is *different* (whether newer or older).

Answer (score 6):

#### POSIX solution

Other answers use `-u`  or `-n` options of `cp`. Neither of these is [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html); nor is `rsync` from yet another answer; nor is `yes` used in one of the comments.

Still, we can reproduce `yes n` with a `while` loop. This leads to the following POSIX solution:

```sh
while true; do echo n; done | cp -Ri /origin /destination 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `cp -rn <sourcedirname>/. <destdirname>`

The r switch makes the copy recursive over the directories.

The n switch (long version no-clobber) ensures existing files are never over-written.

The '`/.`' after the sourcedirname ensures that it does not become a subdirectory under the destdirname instead of all contents of the former being copied to the latter.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for me. I used rsync and rsync ate my full cpu, my computer was too hot in high temperature, so I prefer using cp.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the "-u" option for the `cp` command.

Comment: Disagree that using -u is a good idea. -u copies only when source is newer or destination is missing. Original poster's issue was caused by file copy breaking for whatever reason. OP would therefore have half-written file that wasn't updated when re-running the copy. That file might be important to someone! **rsync solves this problem.**

Answer (score 2):

All above answers are correct but if you are doing this recursively then

you should do:

```
 cp -rn SOURCE_PATH DESTINATION_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be copying as root to maintain permissions/ownership

```
# cp -au
```

Also look at rsync

Answer (score 0):

If your source location is a remote file system, and you don't have shell access to it (and thus can't use `rsync`), then this might help:

```sh
cd /local/destination/path
echo "reget /remote/source/path" | sftp -r sftp://username@domainOrIpAddress
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26411449/11950764) answer.

Note that `reget` is the same as `get -a`. It checks for the presence of half-copied files and finishes copying them.