# Copy files that don't exist in higher directory

Tags: linux

I currently know [how to copy files that don't exist](https://superuser.com/a/118783/172321) in the target directory. This allows me to copy from `src`  to `dst` just as I would like.

However, now I want to copy from `src` to `dst/2016-01-05` BUT only the files in `src` that do not exist anywhere inside `dst`.

## Example

Suppose the start situation is

```
src/f1.txt
src/f2.txt
src/f3.txt

dst/2016-01-04/f1.txt
dst/2016-01-05/f0.txt
```

Then, after doing the copy, the end situation should be:

```
src/f1.txt
src/f2.txt
src/f3.txt

dst/2016-01-04/f1.txt
dst/2016-01-05/f0.txt

dst/2016-01-05/f2.txt
dst/2016-01-05/f3.txt
```

In general I would not like to overwrite existing files. Even if the source is updated.

Comment: Are there subdirectories in `src/`? If so, how are they handled in `dst/`? Is the date-coded directory immediately under `dst/` or between the source directory and the target file?

Comment: @AFH There are no subdirectories in `src`. In the `dst` directory, I will create a folder with the current date, for example `dst/2016-01-04`, and put all files in there that did not exist anywhere in `dst` yet. (I do not want to depend on how long the files have existed in `src`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:-

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
ls -A src/ | while f=`line`; do if [ ! -f "dst/*/$f" ]; \
                 then mkdir -p "dst/$today"; cp "src/$f" "dst/$today/$f"; fi; done
```

Notes:-

1. Compared with the alternative of `for f in src/*; ...`, using `ls` strips the directory from the source name, and `-A` includes file names beginning with `.`, .
2. If there are subdirectories in `src/` you will need to to use `find` in the source directory and strip `src/` from the name with `-printf %P\\n`.
3. If you don't have the `line` command you can use `while read f; ...`, but this does not work for file names with leading and trailing white space (even `line` fails if the file name contains a new-line character - for this you would need to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`).